# VideoJs autoplay not tiggered when using addevent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, jquery-events

I followed the quick-start guide for [videojs](http://videojs.com/docs/setup/) and placed the following code inside the body of my html document:

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="941" 
      height="531" autoplay preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="dummy_url">
</video>
```

All works fine. Autoplay and controls in place.

As I needed to remove the video when the video ends I placed the following code right after the video tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _V_("video").addEvent("ended", videoEnd);

    function videoEnd(){
        $('#divId').slideToggle("slow");
        setTimeout("$('#divId').remove()", 700);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that everytime I try to detect some video the autoplay doesn't work anymore. Even the following doesn't trigger autoplay:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _V_("video").ready(function(){

        var myPlayer = this;

        // EXAMPLE: Start playing the video.
        myPlayer.play();

    });

    _V_("video").addEvent("ended", videoEnd);

    function videoEnd(){
        $('#divId').slideToggle("slow");
        setTimeout("$('#divId').remove()", 700);
    }
</script>
```

Any idea on how I can keep the autoplay and listen to the ended event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this is the most correct implementation but:

```
<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
     width="941" height="531" autoplay preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
     <source type="video/mp4" src="dummy_url">
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    interval = setInterval(videoLoaded, 100);

    function videoEnd(){
            $('#someid').slideToggle("slow");
            setTimeout("$('#someid').remove()", 700);
        }

    function videoLoaded(){
        if(!_V_.players.video){
            return false;
        }

        _V_.players.video.play();
        _V_.players.video.addEvent("ended", videoEnd);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

</script>
```

From what I have read, the alternative is to load the video through js only.

This is a problem (from what I read) with the way videojs initializes the video objects. More details can be found [here](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1171-videojs-playerinit-ignores-data-setup-attribute-content-broken-video-if-dom-ready-event-tries-to-use-player).

Hope it helps some *bumper* :)

Answer (score 0):

actually better is to start videoLoaded function using setTimeout function, because you can not control your player (if you will need it).